# What's a good site for getting answers to computer software or hardware problems?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a site where I can ask questions about a computer problem I have - one where I can get a reliable answer quickly.

Is there such a site?

Comment: How is this off topic for a site about web applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [SuperUser.](https://superuser.com/) From [the FAQ:](https://superuser.com/faq)

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts
>   and power users. If you have a
>   question about
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software